# How to access the GUI in Ubuntu 12.04 while running from a disc?

Tags: live-usb, gui

I am trying to run Ubuntu 12.04 from a disc, without installing it on the hard disk.

All I can access is a command line but no graphical interface. The command line is `ubuntu@ubuntu` or something similar.

How do I get a GUI in live mode?

Comment: Have you tried running `startx`?

Comment: What's the file you downloaded to burn onto the disc? You might have downloaded the server version which does not have a GUI natively.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ startx
```

Is the command to start up the GUI. However if it did not start automatically then there is probably something wrong that prevented it from started in the first place.